# github is not updating changes

Tags: github, push

I'm trying to push changes onto my github repo. Every time I do, it says that everything is up to date, but when I actually look through my repo, nothing is updated. I've googled it, but none of the solutions that have popped up have done anything.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have first committed changes by

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Changes"
```

And then you should be able to push.

Otherwise, you should also first try to pull latest changes from the server.

> Make sure that after every command you have not received any error. If
>   so please post this here.
>
> Also check that a correct origin has been configured.

If referential integrity has been broken:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

If referential integrity is intact:

```
git remote show origin
```